# .well-known/acme-challenge

Tags: nginx, centos, centos6

Пытаюсь получить сертификат с sslforfree.com там надо ссылку вида `site.ru/.well-known/acme-challenge/test` но у меня ошибка

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.10.2
```

Подскажите как правильно сделать?

---

в логе:

> 2018/01/12 22:04:07 [error] 24924#24924: *714345 openat() "/usr/local/mgr5/www/letsencrypt/test" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 0.0.0.0, server: site.ru, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/test HTTP/1.1", host: "site.ru"

Comment: А вы положили требуемый файл для требуемой ссылки? Как именно вы пытаетесь получить сертификат?

Comment: @andreymal да я создал папки и файлы загрузил как нужно, но по сссылке не открывается файл. Если убрать точку перед `.well-known` то тогда открывает :)))

Comment: Очевидно, вы создали папку без точки, а надо создать с точкой, чо

Comment: @andreymal так вот именно что создал с точкой и не работает, если убираю точку то открывает.

Comment: А у меня работает. Покажите наиподробнейшую информацию, что как вы создаёте и что как проверяете, что как работает и что как не работает, а то сейчас выглядит так, будто вы просто точки забываете и отказываетесь это признавать

Comment: @andreymal ну не совсем я плохой такой, [Вот]: http://f3.s.qip.ru/T5tGu3q1.png

Comment: Ну ладно :) И `site.ru/.well-known/acme-challenge/test` не открывается?

Comment: @andreymal все верно, блин если б там не было сайта я б вам и ftp дал. http://f2.s.qip.ru/T5tGu3q2.png

Comment: Значит какое-то дело в настройках nginx, возможно в error.log он написал, где он пытался искать файл и почему не нашёл

Comment: @andreymal тут Арать можно? Я туда смотрел, там было пусто. Щас нашел: `2018/01/12 22:04:07 [error] 24924#24924: *714345 openat() "/usr/local/mgr5/www/letsencrypt/test" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 0.0.0.0, server: site.ru, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/test HTTP/1.1", host: "site.ru"` теперь я решил вопрос, спасибо!

Comment: @wwwplaton напишите решение, возможно кому-то пригодится )

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего, в конфигурации программы *nginx* указан псевдоним (*alias*) для запроса `/.well-known/acme-challenge`, ведущий в каталог `/usr/local/mgr5/www/letsencrypt`